# Python to Java code conversion

Tags: java, python

Could anyone give me a hand converting this Python script to Java?

This is the code

```
theHex = input("Hex: ").split() 
theShift = int(input("Shift: ")) 
result = "" 
for i in range (len(theHex)): 
    result += (hex((int(theHex[i],16) + theShift))).split('x')[1] + " " 
    print(result)
```

Here is what I've got

```
System.out.print("Please enter the hex: ");
String theHex = BIO.getString();
String[] theHexArray = theHex.split(" ");

System.out.print("Please enter the value to shift by: ");
int theShift = BIO.getInt();

String result[] = null;

for( int i = 0 ; i < theHex.length() ; i++ ){
     //result += (hex((int(theHex[i],16) + theShift))).split('x')[1] + " "
}

toText(result[]);
```

BIO is a class I have to collect Strings and Ints. Think of it as basically a scanner.

Could anyone help me translate the last line?

EDIT
Here is the toText method

```
public static void toText(String theHexArray[]){
    String theHex = "";

    for(int i = 0 ; i < theHexArray.length ; i++ ){
        theHex += theHexArray[i];
    }

    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    try{
        for (int i = 0; i < theHex.length(); i+=2){
            String str = theHex.substring(i, i+2);
            output.append((char)Integer.parseInt(str, 16));
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("ERROR");
    }
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Comment: I really question these so called "helper" classes that are really just an extra layer between you and a scanner.. To the point: don't try to one-on-one translate the code. Split it up and see what it is trying to do, then implement it step by step.

Comment: You mean to print the array ? `java.util.Arrays.toString(result)`

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I'm only using it for simplicity as thats what I've gotten used to. As for the comment, I've attempted to. However I've not been able to find what it's doing as I'm not familiar with python. I've looked at docs and not found it. If you could explain it in a java oriented way that would probably help.

Comment: @PeterMmm No, I'm converting the data in the array from hex to ascii and did it in another method to keep my code a bit cleaner in my view

Comment: What do you mean converting from hex to ascii?  Do you have a number in hex that you want in a decimal-formatted string?

Comment: @IanMcLaird I've sorted out the conversion, thats not an issue. I've shown the code in the main post. All I need now is the line left to translate that actually shifts the hex. If you are able to help. By hex I'm meaning "7E 80 84 82" etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you're making this rather more work for yourself than you really need to, but here goes.

If you're going to go for a line-by-line port, then *do that*.

1. Don't declare result as an array of strings.  That'll just give you a headache.  Make it either a `StringBuilder` or a plain `String` as I do here (`StringBuilder` will be more efficient, admittedly, but this is probably easier to understand).  This is also more similar to the python code you already have.
2. Understand what your python code is doing.  It's taking a string in hex format, parsing it to an integer, adding a value (`theShift`), converting *back* into hex, and then getting just the numeric part of the string (without the leading `0x`).  So in Java, that loop goes like this.  (**NOTE**: in Java `Integer.toString(x, 16)` does *not* print the leading `0x`, so we don't need to chop it off).

   ```
   String result = "";
   for (String thisHex : theHexArray) {
       result += Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(thisHex, 16) + theShift, 16) + " ";
   }
   ```
3. Lose the `toText` method.  At this point you have the string you wanted, so that method doesn't really do anything anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of whether you decide to translate line by line, or work on understanding the code and then write a Java based solution to the problem, you need to break down that last line to understand it.  Try looking at it like this:

```
result += (hex((int(theHex[i],16) + theShift))).split('x')[1] + " "
```

is the same as -

```
val1 = int(theHex[i],16)
val2 = (val1 + theShift)
val3 = hex(val2)
val4 = (val3).split('x')
result += val4[1] + " "
```

Now you can see more clearly what is being called.  Your next step is to look up what the int, hex and split calls are doing.